How can I see how many times a function has been called when viewing a thread in Xcode?
In Xcode it shows me the thread for a bad memory access, but I want a way to find out how many times the loops/ functions along the way have been successfully called before that point from any earlier part in that thread.
So like for example if I have a linked list that includes a function:
class LinkedList{

public:
     
     add(int val){
          Node* added = new Node(val);
          if (first != nullptr) added->next = first;
          first = added;
     }
   
     LinkedList(){
          first = nullptr;
     }

     Node first;

     class Node{
          Node next;
          int val;
          Node(int val){
               this->val = val;
          }
     }


     int findVal(int n) {
          return recursiveSearch(first,n);
     }

     int recursiveSearch(Node* current, int n){
          if (current->val == n) return current;
          return recursiveSearch(current->next, n);
     }
}

Say I have the main function initialize the linked list and then search it for a value that isn't in the list, it's going to give me a bad memory access error.
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    LinkedList* ls = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        ls->add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1;i++){
        std::cout << ls->findVal(i);
    }
}

So Xcode will show me a path to the error: main -> ls.findVal(i) -> LinkedList::findVal -> LinkedList::recursiveSearch -> current->val.
But how can I also have it display that the loop ran called ls.findVal() n times before the n+1 time broke it?
Moreover, is there a way to track all the iterations of each of my functions to see what the variables values were during each without having to manually put a ton of print statements in my code? To have it list out each individual call in order through the entire process up to the error, starting from the very beginning, without skipping the functions that are returned successfully?
and additional question-> is there any way I can track variables or data structures on their own, so it shows me the history of that data type being updated?

LinkedList ls = new LinkedList();...ls.add(i); -- This is not real C++ code.  The new in C++ returns a pointer, not an object, thus ls.add(i); could never had compile successfully, let alone ls should have been a pointer.

Check out thread_local to declare a thread specific static. Then increment it on each call.

"But how can I also have it display that the loop ran called ls.findVal() n times before the n+1 time broke it?" -- So, you want to know how to get your debugger to tell you the value of the i variable?

@JaMiT i isn't always there to show the iteration number. while loop, for example. obviously I could always solve this stuff by entering extra variables and doing print statements but I was wondering if there was some way Xcode could inherently track it.

That recursiveSearch() function is gonna need two more things; firstly a way to return did not find.  It's probably best to return a std::optional here, with the value unset if it did not find the value.  Second the function will need to stop at the end of the list, when node == nullptr.  That's a good place to return the did not find condition.

@CoinZwischenzug i isn't always there to show the iteration number" -- The question you asked specifies "the loop ran called ls.findVal() n times". Not an arbitrary loop, but this particular loop in your code, in which i is available. If you had meant to ask more generally, you should revise your question.

Do you want to know the whole history or do you want to track down where things went wrong? How about breakpoints with a condition and/or action?
